# Align SVG image on button VMware Clarity

Tags: html, css, svg, vmware-clarity

I'm playing with the [tabler svg icon sprites](https://github.com/tabler/tabler-icons) and would like to use them in my angular app which uses [VMware Clarity Design](https://clarity.design/).

I have the images rendering inside my button using the sprite file but the image does not align with text:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-icon btn-outline btn-outline-primary">
  <svg width="24" height="24">
    <use xlink:href="assets/tabler/tabler-sprite.svg#tabler-anchor"></use>
  </svg>
  Test Tabler
</button>
```

I've tried vertical-align styles on button and svg with no effect.  Googling svg centering show LOTS of spacing padding examples, but have not hit on one that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had misplaced class tag in the "use" tag instead of the "svg" (not shown in my original post).  Corrected/working code below:

style:

```
.tabler {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

html:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-icon btn-outline btn-outline-primary">
  <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="tabler">
    <use xlink:href="assets/tabler/tabler-sprite.svg#tabler-anchor"></use>
  </svg>
  Test Tabler
</button>
```

This now achieves my objective of vertically centering the svg on my button styled with clarity.

Comment: You could also load the tabler icons with the ClarityIcons API: https://clarity.design/icons/api